# How can I correctly implement this Spring Data JPA named query that involves a JOIN between 2 tables?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring application using **Spring Data JPA**. I am implemented the **named query method** to implement my queries. I am experiencing some difficulties trying to implement a named query that involves a join between 2 tables\entity classes.

So I have these 2 entity classes:

1) **Room** representing a room of an accomodation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_accomodation_fk", nullable = false)
    private Accomodation accomodation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
    private RoomTipology roomTipology;

    @Column(name = "room_number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "room_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "room_description")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "max_people")
    private Integer maxPeople;

    @Column(name = "is_enabled")
    private Boolean isEnabled;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

As you can see this class contains this field:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
private RoomTipology roomTipology;
```

that link many Room instance to a RoomTipology instancce.

2) Then I have **RoomTipology** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room_tipology")
public class RoomTipology implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tipology_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "tipology_description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Date timeStamp;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private List<Room> rooms;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private RoomRate roomRate;

    // CONSTRUCTOR, GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

Then I have this repository clas for the **RoomTipology** entity class, something like:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface RoomTipologyDAO extends JpaRepository<RoomTipology, Long> {

    RoomTipology findByRoomTipology_Room(Room room);

}
```

I have try in this way but it can't work and I obtain the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomTipologyDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property roomTipology found for type RoomTipology!
```

I want to retrieve the related **RoomTipology** instance starting from the **Room**. Basically I want to translate this SQL query into a Spring Data JPA named query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `room_tipology` rt 
INNER JOIN room r
ON rt.id = r.id_room_tipology_fk
WHERE r.id = 7
```

where r.id is the value of the id field of the **Room** entity.

I know that if I already have a **Room** object I can obtain this information doing:

```
room.getRoomTipology()
```

But sometimes I just have the id of a **Room** instance and I want directly retrieve the related **RoomTipology** object.

How can I do it using named query?

Comment: Would `EntityManager#getReference(Room.class, 7L).getRoomTipology()` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Name your method the way you think it should best be named, pass a roomId rather than a room, since that's your actual search parameter, and annotate the method with

```
@Query("select t from Room r join r.roomTypology t where r = :roomId")
```

Comment: I know that I can do it using HQL but how can I do using the named query?